# Animation transition scale does not work in swiftui

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to run the following transition in a View but does not work as expected. The HELLO WORLD Text should be at first visible. Then on tap of the button it should scale based on the private var zoomOutTransition. The transition is triggered but i see a second Text staying on the screen. Any help appreciated!!!

```
import SwiftUI

public struct SimpleAnimation: View {

        @State
    private var scaleEightImage = false
    
    
    private var zoomOutTransition: AnyTransition {
        return .asymmetric(
            insertion: .identity.animation(nil),
            removal: .scale(
                scale: 1000, anchor: UnitPoint(x: 0.494, y: 0.05))
                    .animation(
                        .easeInOut(duration: 10.0)
                        .delay(0.1)
                    )
        )
    }
    
    public var body: some View {

        ZStack {
            Color.clear
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                if scaleEightImage {
                    Text("HELLO WORLD!")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                        .transition(zoomOutTransition)
                } else if !scaleEightImage {
                    Text("HELLO WORLD!")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                }

            }
            
            VStack {
                Button {
                     DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
                    withAnimation {
                        viewModel.scaleEightImage.toggle()
                    }
}
                } label: {
                    Text("tappppp me")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                }
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: I can't find the declaration of variable `viewModel` in your code. And I can't find in your question the code of the view model either, to understand how it behaves (`@Published var`? `ObservableObject class`?).

Comment: @HunterLion I have added a much simpler example thanks for responding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text stays on the screen because you have 2 `Text()` views - one that shows when `scaleEightImage` is `true`, another one for when `scaleEightImage` is `false`.

You just need to show the text only when `scaleEightImage` is `false`:

```
VStack {
    Spacer()
    if !scaleEightImage {
        Text("HELLO WORLD!")
            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            .transition(zoomOutTransition)
    }
}
```